# How to uninstall Uget from ubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, uget

I was trying to use this software to download some classes, but now i dont need it anymore, and i was trying to remove, and i did:

`sudo apt-get remove uget`

But every time that i use ctrl+c to save the links that i need or to pass for someone, one window of this software open on my screen, and this is very bad.

Do you know what is wrong in this case ?

I have a ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge uget`  https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/uget?type=uninstall

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks for your comment, I tried to restart and then the uget wasn't there anymore, so i think your comment plus a restart solved it.